# Would saying "if" in place of "whether" be a big mistake?

Tags: whether-if

For example, in the expression "I don't know whether I'm coming or going", would saying *if* in place of *whether* be a big mistake? Would doing it in written English be an error too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, *if* and *whether* can be substituted for each other. In certain situations, they have different meanings. For example:

> I don't know **whether** I should arrive on Friday or Saturday
>
> I don't know **if** I should arrive on Friday or Saturday

The first sentence implies that the person will arrive, but they are not sure when. The second sentence could be read that the person might not arrive at all.

Comment: The example is a common expression meaning basically "I'm confused." More explanation [here](http://www.jetenglish.com/359).

Answer (score 8):

Formally, if should be used when you have a conditional sentence and where whether should be used when you are showing that two alternatives are possible.

In the sentence asked, both are correct.

Answer (score 4):

In the questioned sentence, "if" can be used to imply that the person saying it may not be either coming or going, but could be standing still, or even running around in circles.

"Whether" implies that "coming" and "going" are the only possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

*If* could be used in place of *whether*.

They would have the same effect, and the same meaning.

So no, it wouldn't be a big mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I find that *if* is commonly substituted for *whether* in informal English (the reverse does not happen). This is one of my personal bugbears: I try to get it "right", but in practise most people are happy to let it slide.